# Electric potential energy between fast moving charges

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, charge, potential-energy

It is well known that in static system, electric potential energy of system conducted with two sphere charges, $q_1$ and $q_2$ with distance $d$ and radius $R$, is $E=\frac{q_1 q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 d}+\frac{q_1^2+q_2^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0 R}$. But what if the charges are moving? Not just moving slow, but with high speed enough to make relativistic phenomenon. Suppose that two sphere charges with charge $q_1$ and $q_2$ with distance $d$ and radius $R$, but they are moving toward each other with speed $v_1$(speed of charge 1) and $v_2$(speed of charge 2). Then what is the (electromagnetic) potential energy of the system?

Comment: Can you calculate $d(v_1,v_2)=f(v_1,v_2)$?

Comment: I assumed that the charges are moving in constant velocity. So it would be $d_0 - (v_1+v_2)t$.

Comment: Ok. So doesn't that answer your question, re. Pot. En. $E$?

Comment: Well, I saw of the electric field of fast moving charge. Its field was different from charge that is at rest. So I thought that potential energy is also different. Is something that I am misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm not sure. Check your reference text.